# How can one controller observe events on an arbitrary controller/model in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have this very simple model backed by a nearly empty controller:

```
App.EnergySegment = Ember.Object.extend({
    identity: 'segment',
    isSelected: false,
});
App.SegmentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    // simple properties
    debug: true,

    // actions
    actions: {
        toggleSegment: function() {
            var status = this.get('isSelected');
            this.set('isSelected', !status);
        }
    }
});
```

I have a totally different controller that needs to total the cost of all selected segments:

```
App.DashboardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: 'segment',

    cost: function() {
        alert('a selection occurred!')
        return '1.00';
    }.property('controllers.segment.isSelected')
});
```

Why isn't my Dashboard cost function being triggered when I select a segment?  (I'm not using Ember Data, fyi.)

Comment: Could you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: Is a dashboard responsible for multiple segments?

Comment: @AmirT Hi again :)  Yes, the segments contain various properties (including a cost) and the dashboard will display variations of those properties.  For example, an average cost for all selected segments and various charts.

Comment: Looks like @Renato is on the path of the plural segments controller which I think is the issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `property` and `observes` up. Computed properties are only triggered when they are `get()`.

```
App.DashboardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['segment'],

    cost: function() {
        var segment = this.get("controllers.segment");

        // Example: the cost changes if the segment selection
        // changes
        if(segment.get('isSelected')) {
          return '1.00';
        } else {
          return '0.00';
        }
    }.property('controllers.segment.isSelected'),

    // When the segment is selected/deselected, the alert
    // will pop up
    _selectedSegmentDidChange: function() {
        alert('a selection occurred!');
    }.observes('controllers.segment.isSelected'),
});
```

---

It seems from the comments that the `observes`/`property` confusion is not really the issue, but the fact that you are using an `ObjectController` vs a `ArrayController`. Here's what a `SegmentsController` might look like:

```
// Mind the plural
App.SegmentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selected: Ember.computed.filterBy('content', 'isSelected'),
});
```

From that, we can make the `DashboardController` work on the collection:

```
App.DashboardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['segments'], // Mind the plural again

  // Make a shorter alias
  _selectedSegments: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.segments.selected"),

  cost: function() {
    var costs = this.get("_selectedSegments").getEach("cost");

    return costs.reduce(function(total, current) {
      return total + current;
    }, 0);
  }.property("_selectedSegments.@each.cost"),      
});
```

You might want to take a look at this example: http://jsbin.com/ALIBewA/1/edit

Comment: I am using {{cost}} in a template - doesn't that count?

Comment: I have seen `..DidChange` pop up here and there.  Does this mean something particular to Ember?

Comment: It's just a naming convention for observers, but you can name them however you want. AFAIK it's not something Ember relies upon

Comment: Well, that isn't working for me yet.  This should fire whenever any segment changes - it isn't binding to a specific element, right?  Then I would have access to that segment via `this`, but not to all selected segments, right?

Comment: You need a `SegmentsController` then - an `ArrayController` that contains all segments. I will try to make a demo

Comment: @doub1ejack check out if it helps now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41136/discussion-between-doub1ejack-and-renato-zannon)